# Django Empty page alone takes 2 seconds to load

Tags: django, nginx

I am doing my django project with nginx on google compute engine.

My view file is,

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home(request):
    return render_to_response('html/index.html',RequestContext(request))
```

and my template file index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Home </title>
</head>
<body>
Wel come to my new project
</body>
</html>
```

While calling this page alone takes 2.75 seconds to load completely on my server.

It takes 1.8second for FFTB ( waiting time)
Is there any configuration problem for this latency?

my settings file

```
"""
Django settings for audiotube project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os


#Base root is for outside of the project structure
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

rsa_private_key = BASE_DIR + "/lib/rsa/id_rsa"

#Package root is for inside the project
PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '46=+9k)k25rb(b9&&wy9y_xtn3rx2stl#%+0-5o-$-un9o&4hn'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','example.com', '*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #This is for the site name and inbuild framework
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app0',
    'app1',
    'ckeditor',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'compressor',
    'template_timings_panel',

)
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    # other finders..
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',    
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'hostingaddre',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = None

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

SITE_ID = 1

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/mysite/staticfiles/'


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static"),
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "media")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.



TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join("templates"),
]


#Template context processors



TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
)


# This two setting needed for downloading CKEDITOR

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'UltraFull',
        'height': 300,
        'toolbar_UltraFull': [
            ['Font', 'FontSize', 'Format'],
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'],
            [
                'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-',
                'Outdent', 'Indent', '-',
                'Blockquote', '-',
                'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'
            ],
            ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
            ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'PageBreak', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar'],
            ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
            ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
            ['Maximize', 'Source'],
        ],        
        'toolbarCanCollapse': False,
    },
    'awesome_ckeditor': {
        'toolbar': 'UltraFull',
        'height': 300,
        'toolbar_UltraFull': [
            ['Font', 'FontSize', 'Format'],
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'],
            [
                'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-',
                'Outdent', 'Indent', '-',
                'Blockquote', '-',
                'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'
            ],
            ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
            ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'PageBreak', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar'],
            ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
            ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
            ['Maximize', 'Source'],
        ],        
        'toolbarCanCollapse': False,
    },
}



AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'users.backends.EmailAuthBackend',
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY ="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET ="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY ="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
SOCIAL_AUTH_FORCE_EMAIL_VALIDATION = True



EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

SITE_URL="http://example.com:8000/"


'''
#Use this for exception handling
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',

)
'''

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'users.pipeline.require_email',
    #'social.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'users.pipeline.save_profile',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    #'social.pipeline.debug.debug'
)

# login redirect urls
LOGIN_URL = "/signin"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/dashboard"
DOMAIN = "http://example.com:8000"



if DEBUG:
    INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    )

    INSTALLED_APPS += (
        'debug_toolbar',
    )

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = (
    'template_timings_panel.panels.TemplateTimings.TemplateTimings',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.version.VersionDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
        #'debug_toolbar.panels.settings_vars.SettingsVarsDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeaderDebugPanel',
        #'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.request_vars.RequestVarsDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.template.TemplateDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CacheDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalDebugPanel',
        #'debug_toolbar.panels.logger.LoggingPanel',
    )

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
        'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
    }


PREPEND_WWW = True

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
    }
}


TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
       'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
       'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
   )),
)
```

In example.com which is inside /etc/nginx/site-enabled and site-available

```
server {

    listen   80;
    server_name myservername.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;


    error_page 502 =200 @maintenance;

    location @maintenance {
        root /path/to/static/offline/files;
        try_files $uri /index.html =503;
    }
   location /static/ {

       alias  /home/sim/5vs/staticfiles/;

    }

    location /media/ {
       alias  /home/sim/5vs/myproject/myproject/site_media/media/;
       expires 30d;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;


    }
}
```

in nginx.conf file has

```
user root;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;



    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Could you please tell why it takes long time and what's wrong in my configuration.

On using Profiler

Total time: 1.89419 s
File: /home/staging/live/users/views.py
Function: comingsoon_view at line 93

## Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents

```
93                                           def comingsoon_view(request):
94         1            2      2.0      0.0     temp = {}
95         1      1894189 1894189.0    100.0    return render(request, 'pages/comingsoon.html',temp)
```

Comment: What are you using to serve from the upstream port 8000?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't have and idea about server side integration. I have used some manual to configure this. Even this project is running with out that check the updated file . Please tell you suggestion I will check and let you know.

Comment: You've set nginx to point to an upstream server on port 8000. What is running there? You must have something, otherwise your app wouldn't be responding at all. Are you using gunicorn? Or are you (as Yevgeniy hints) using the Django runserver? If the latter, you **must absolutely not do that**.

Comment: Actually am using gunicorn to run my project

Answer (score 0):

User using debug server with DEBUG=True setting to run django project. It enables DEBUG toolbar - which is really slow. It's normal time with this settings. If you'll disable this - I think everything will be fine.

If you will still have troubles - I recommend you to check django debug server response time(python manage.py runserver). If it faster then problem is nginx configuration or, if the same - you should check timings with [lineprofiler](https://github.com/dmclain/django-debug-toolbar-line-profiler).

If it's production configuration - don't use debug server on production. You should use [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) or something similar to run django projects.

Comment: Even the debug is disable it takes same time to execute and django debug server and nginx is also more or less same not big difference.  I will check with line profiler and gunicorn and let you know.

Comment: I have used line prifiler , I attached the result in my question . Please look and let me know what else I have to do.

Comment: Next steps should be:
1. Disable social-auth middlewares
2. Switch to memcached or other available in-memory cache backend
3. Check that you really disabled DEBUG setting (./manage.py shell ;from django.conf import settings; print settings.DEBUG)
4. Run project locally  - may be google compute engine is the reason? )

Usually django works fine with such simple project.

Comment: 5. May be google compute engine file access is slow - try to use cached template loader(with default loader django searches and loads template from filesystem for every request). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader

Comment: Actually I have already added the cache template in my settings file. You can see in my question. My question is Wile using line profiler on rendering the values to the template takes more time. around 40 var to template takes 10mins. How could we reduce the template rendering time.

Comment: Actually you can go deeper with lineprofiler - inside render function. And so on until you will find the reason.

Comment: Could you please see here http://staging.audiotube.com/registration/ which takes more time . Sorry I am new to here please look and tell me the suggestion.

Comment: I see that simple string concatenation takes 17% of your time. May be processor is not good?
17.1% of all request time: for i in genre:

Comment: I using google compute engine only . You see the remaining percentage is takes for rendering . how could we reduce that?

Comment: Strange thing that I don't see sql-requests in django-debug-toolbar - it's really helpful feature. I can only guess.
values_list - is lazy, so request happens on this line "for i in genre:"
Could you try to set genre=[] and subGenres=[] to disable any sql-requests? It's really hard to debug through stackoverflow )